# TreeView - Iterate through all nodes, stop at first visible

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, treeview, iteration

I'm having a mental block right now, this can't be that hard.

I have a function which should get the last visible node in the TreeView. First I want to go to the first visible node and then second from there on go as long as node.IsVisible().

Here's what I have:

```
public TreeNode GetLastVisibleNode()
    {
        var node = treeControl1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(x => x.IsVisible).FirstOrDefault();
        TreeNode retVal = node;
        while (node != null && node.IsVisible)
        {
            if (!node.IsSelected)
                retVal = node;
            node = node.NextVisibleNode;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

As you can see I made it to iterate to the last visible node when I have the first visible (HOORAY) but my approach of getting the first visible is WRONG (OHHHHH!)

I noticed that treeControl1.Nodes only gives me the parent nodes but obvioulsy I want to get the first visible node of all nodes.

I also know that I probably need a recursive method but as I said in the beginning, I'm having a mental block right now and want to have this fixed quite soon :(

Comment: What do you mean by _first_ - the most left node, the most bottom node or the first node in the collection (this is what you seem to be doing currently)?

Comment: The first node visible in my TreeView - view.

With my first line in the function it works to get the first visible parent node (because TreeView.Nodes only returns a list of nodes which can also have a list of nodes which can … ) but it should also work if it's let's say a child of a child of a child of a parent or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that TreeView.TopNode gets me the first visible node.

From there on I just iterated through the list as long as node.IsVisible and node != null.

```
public TreeNode GetLastVisibleNode()
{
    TreeNode node = treeControl1.TopNode;
    TreeNode retVal;
    do
    {
        retVal = node;
        node = node.NextVisibleNode;
    } while (node != null && node.IsVisible);

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably solve your problem:

```
public TreeNode GetLastVisibleNode ()
{
    var node = treeControl1.Nodes.Cast <TreeNode> ().Select (GetFirstVisibleNode).
                            FirstOrDefault (first => first != null);

    var retVal = node;
    while (node != null && node.IsVisible)
    {
        if (!node.IsSelected)
            retVal = node;
        node = node.NextVisibleNode;
    }

    return retVal;


    TreeNode GetFirstVisibleNode (TreeNode parentNode) =>
        parentNode.IsVisible
            ? parentNode
            : parentNode.Nodes.Cast <TreeNode> ().Select (GetFirstVisibleNode).
                         FirstOrDefault (childFirstNode => childFirstNode != null);
}
```

However, I don't see what exactly your trying to achieve. If this solution doesn't work for you, you should try to phrase your problem better.

It actually seems as if you could solve your problem by directly receiving the *last* visible node:

```
public TreeNode GetLastVisibleNode ()
{
    return treeControl1.Nodes.Cast <TreeNode> ().Select (GetLastVisibleNode).
                            LastOrDefault (first => first != null);


    TreeNode GetLastVisibleNode (TreeNode parentNode) =>
        parentNode.IsVisible
            ? parentNode
            : parentNode.Nodes.Cast <TreeNode> ().Select (GetLastVisibleNode).
                         LastOrDefault(childFirstNode => childFirstNode != null);
}
```

Because of a lack of a working environment I couldn't test this, but it should actually do the same.

---

Ok, I think I should explain my code a little bit.
This part:

```
TreeNode GetFirstVisibleNode (TreeNode parentNode) =>
        parentNode.IsVisible
            ? parentNode
            : parentNode.Nodes.Cast <TreeNode> ().Select (GetFirstVisibleNode).
                         FirstOrDefault (childFirstNode => childFirstNode != null);
```

Actually does the same as this:

```
TreeNode GetFirstVisibleNode (TreeNode parentNode)
{
    if (parentNode.IsVisible)
        return parentNode;
    foreach (var childNode in parentNode.Nodes.Cast <TreeNode> ())
    {
        var childFirstNode = GetFirstVisibleNode (childNode);
        if (childFirstNode != null)
            return childFirstNode;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The first Linq query is similiar.

The part after the return statement isn't wrong there - it's called a local function. You could of course put it outside the function, but as you'll never need it in another method than in `GetLastVisibleNode()` you can put it inside of it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) you can read more about it.

Comment: This does exactly what I want but I have no idea what you did there :D

Probably because I've only worked with Java so far but I'm doing an internship right now where I have to code in C# so LINQ statements are completely new to me (I found the other one in already existing code).

But maybe you have to edit your provided code and put the second part outside of the function because it's after the return